# Dio package timeout error, (io_adapter error dio)

Tags: dart, dio

This is my api code to send request uing dio and taking response, I have added the baseoption for connectionTimeout to be 3 seconds.

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:pretty_dio_logger/pretty_dio_logger.dart';

const String baseURL = "BASE_URL-HERE";
const Map<String, dynamic> defaultHeaders = {'apisecret': "SECRET"};

class Api {
  final Dio _dio = Dio(
    BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: baseURL,
      headers: defaultHeaders,
      contentType: "application/json",
      connectTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 3),
    ),
  );

  Api() {
    _dio.interceptors.add(
      PrettyDioLogger(
        requestBody: true,
        requestHeader: true,
        responseBody: true,
        responseHeader: true,
      ),
    );
    _dio.httpClientAdapter = HttpClientAdapter();
  }

  Dio get sendRequest => _dio;
}

class ApiResponse {
  bool success;
  dynamic data;
  String? message;

  ApiResponse({required this.success, this.data, this.message});

  factory ApiResponse.fromResponse(Response response) {
    try {
      final data = response.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return ApiResponse(
        success: data["success"],
        data: data["data"],
        message: data["message"] ?? "Unexpected error",
      );
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

I get the exception here in the dio>lib>src>adapters>io_adapter.dart
[io_adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPuXX.png)

This is the Dio log:
[Dio Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Boe9v.png)

This is the call Stack
IOHttpClientAdapter._fetch (c:\Users\aun\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\dio-5.2.1+1\lib\src\adapters\io_adapter.dart:93)
 (Unknown Source:0)
CancelableCompleter.complete. (c:\Users\aun\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\async-2.11.0\lib\src\cancelable_operation.dart:0)
 (Unknown Source:0)

I expext the connection to be stop in the duration i have provide stating the server that i am trying get data from is down or not running.